# Save to binary file

Tags: java, file, binary

I'd like to save data to binary file using java. For example i have the number 101 and in my program the output file have 4 Bytes. How can i save the number only in three bits (101) in the output file ?
My program looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int i = 101;
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file"));
    os.writeInt(i);
    os.close();
}
```

I found something like that: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Bit_Input/Output_Stream_utility_classes_for_efficient_data_transfer

Comment: This makes no sense.  2^6 < 101 < 2^7 so it should take at least 7 bits.  If you want to treat the digits 101 as characters, then use a char array.  And prepare for your program to crash whenever it receives a number that is not composed of 0s and 1s, e.g. 2, 13, 102, etc.

Comment: Number '101' is set of bits. I'd like to create file which stores binary string and have less size (i use Huffman encoding) then original file with text (UTF-8).

Comment: It's not a set of bits.  It's an integer.  The binary representation of that integer is `1100101`.  The only bitset it would make sense to interpret it as is `1100101`.  Use the correct data type.

Comment: I agree with you that i is integer. Code above is only example. But tell me how can i do simple binary bit output ? I use Huffman encode and for example letter 'a' have code 1011 (original 01000001 (UTF-8)). How can i save it to file only on 4 bits ?

Comment: Do you realize, that Huffman (for example) does not store numbers, it stores binary tree navigation path. Decoder also needs the tree, and then takes 0 or 1 branch until it hits a leaf, and gets actual bytes (or whatever)? You can not store bits without count, and read them back. And if you store bits with count, it's less efficient than just always storing 8 bits, even if some of them are "unused".

Answer (score 2):

You can not write less than one byte to a file. If you want to write the binary number 101 then do `int i = 5` and use `os.write(i)` instead. This will write one byte: 0000 0101.

Comment: You don't know what i mean. I don't have save integer number to file but only set of bits (only 1 or 0). For example letter 'a' have binary representation 01000001 (UTF-8) but when i use my Huffman tree 'a' have in binary representation only 1011 and i have to save 'a' in output file only on 4 bits (not 8).

Comment: If you want to store 2 things in one byte you need to manually compose the byte from the parts and then write it: `os.write((val1 & 0x0F) << 4 | (val2 & 0x0f))`

Comment: And the question is how can i store the byte ? Of course in Huffman algorithm letters can have different sizes.

Comment: Yes. You need to convert all list of variable size tokens into a (shorter) list of bytes, and then write them to a file.

Comment: Of course i did it.I have shorter representation of the letters for example 'a' - 1011 but when i try safe 1011 to file of course the output have minimum 4 Bytes not 4 bits. And the question is how i can change it, how i can save sets of bytes? ;)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can't write just 3 bits to a file, memory is aligned at specific values (8, 16, 32, 64 or even 128 bit, this is compiler/platform specific). If you write smaller sizes than that, they will be expanded to match the alignment.

Secondly, the decimal number 101, written in binary is 0b01100101. the binary number 0b00000101, is decimal 5.

Thirdly, these numbers are now only 1 Byte (8 bit) long, so you can use a char instead of an int.

And last but not least, to write non-integer numbers, use `os.write()`

So to get to what you want, first check if you want to write 0b01100101 or 0b00000101. Change the int to a char and to the appropriate number (you can write 0b01100101 in Java). And use os.write()

Answer (score 0):

A really naive implementation, I hope it helps you grasp the idea. Also untested, likely to contain off-by-one errors etc...

```
class BitArray {
  // public fields for example code, in real code encapsulate
  public int bits=0; // actual count of stored bits
  public byte[] buf=new byte[1];

  private void doubleBuf() {
    byte [] tmp = new byte[buf.length * 2];
    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, tmp, 0, buf.length);
    buf = tmp;
  }

  private int arrayIndex(int bitNum) {
    return bitNum / 8;
  }

  private int bitNumInArray(int bitNum) {
    return bitNum & 7; // change to change bit order in buf's bytes
  }

  // returns how many elements of buf are actually in use, for saving etc.
  // note that last element usually contains unused bits.
  public int getUsedArrayElements() {
    return arrayIndex(this.bits-1) + 1;
  }

  // bitvalue is 0 for 0, non-0 for 1
  public void setBit(byte bitValue, int bitNum) { 
    if (bitNum >= this.bits || bitNum < 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    if (bitValue == 0) this.buf[arrayIndex(bitNum)] &= ~((byte)1 << bitNumInArray(bitNum));
    else this.buf[arrayIndex(bitNum)] |= (byte)1 << bitNumInArray(bitNum);
  }

  public void addBit(int bitValue) {
    // this.bits is old bit count, which is same as index of new last bit
    if (this.buf.length <= arrayIndex(this.bits)) doubleBuf(); 
    ++this.bits;
    setBit(bitValue, this.bits-1);
  }

  int readBit(int bitNum) {  // return 0 or 1
    if (bitNum >= this.bits || bitNum < 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    byte value = buf[arrayIndex(bitNum)] & ((byte)1 << bitNumInArray(bitNum));
    return (value == 0) ? 0 : 1;
  }

  void addBits(int bitCount, int bitValues) {
    for (int num = bitCount - 1 ; num >= 0 ; --num) {
      // change loop iteration order to change bit order of bitValues
      addBit(bitValues & (1 << num));
    }
}
```

For efficient solution, it should use int or long array instead of byte array, and include more efficient method for multiple bit addition (add parts of `bitValues` an entire `buf` array element at a time, not bit-by-bit like above).

To save this, you need to save the right number of bytes from buf, calculated by `getUsedArrayElements()`.